# Flatten List of Lists Recursively

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone illustrate or decompose how this recursive function is executed

```
def flatten(S):
    if S == []:
        return S
    if isinstance(S[0], list):
        return flatten(S[0]) + flatten(S[1:])
    return S[:1] + flatten(S[1:])
s=[[1,2],[3,4]]
print("Flattened list is: ",flatten(s))
```

How could I trace the execution of this algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this is a recursive function as you have stated. It is a mostly 'look at the next element and decide what to do with it' method. It is started with the base case.

```py
if S == []:
        return S
```

So this makes sense. You have an empty list, so you would expect to get back an empty list, it's flat.

```py
if isinstance(S[0], list):
    return flatten(S[0]) + flatten(S[1:])
```

Next is the first 'look at the next element, decide what to do', if I receive a list and at the first element there is a list, I will get the program to run this same flattening method on the first element.

But then comes the rest of the list, we don't know if that is flat so I will be doing the same thing for that calling flatten on that as well.

When this returns they should both be flat lists. Adding two lists just joins them together into a new list so this would be returned up a level to the previous call of the recursive method or return to the user.

```
return S[:1] + flatten(S[1:])
```

From before we know that the first element of the list is not a list as the if statement was `if isinstance(S[0], list)` so this is just taking a list with the first element stored in it and just like before running flatten on the rest of the list as we don't know whether the rest of the list is flat or not.

As for tracing, if you don't have Pycharm or pdb is to complex for you. Throw in some prints within each of the if statements. Don't be shy, you're the one that's going to read them. do a `print(f"First element was a list: {S[0]}, {S[1:]}")` that will be fine if you're a beginner dealing with such a small amount of code. Otherwise try PDB or such.